# How to transpose a list of data frames?

Tags: r, lapply, transpose

I have a list of 51 data frames, I need to transpose them and then remove the first two rows the new data frames. I am trying to use lapply, but not familiar with the syntax. My operation is easy to do over one data frame, but using lapply for a list of data frames, is where I'm having trouble. This is what I did to arrive at my final data frame for one element of the list -

```
john<-t(dflist[["df7"]])
john <- john[-c(1,2), ]
```

The removal of rows by row number will be fine for each data frame, since they are same in structure. Built a function to perform the above operation:

```
transposer <- function(df) {
  z<-t(df)
  df<-z[-c(1,2),]
}
```

How do I use this function in `lapply`?

SOLVED :

`soup<-lapply(gooble, transposer)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an approach using `lapply()`.

```
# generate some data frames
set.seed(102134)
id <- 1:5
aList <- lapply(id,function(x){
     data.frame(matrix(runif(50),nrow=10,ncol=5))
})
# transpose and remove first 2 rows
transposeList <- lapply(aList,function(x){
     t(x)[-c(1,2),]
})
# print first transposed data frame
transposeList[[1]]
```

..and the output, noting that rows representing variables `X1` and `X2` in the original data frame have been omitted from the data frame we print:

```
> # print first transposed data frame
> transposeList[[1]]
        [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]       [,6]       [,7]
X3 0.1128006 0.5884873 0.8532827 0.5957727 0.6995990 0.09765447 0.69149804
X4 0.1239681 0.7624771 0.9756067 0.1251610 0.4954070 0.92652298 0.04800376
X5 0.3698154 0.6789413 0.9660355 0.6613972 0.5099627 0.97766102 0.97139575
        [,8]       [,9]     [,10]
X3 0.7731442 0.03916568 0.8787288
X4 0.3829343 0.41939016 0.9668663
X5 0.8865407 0.63437436 0.6774895
>
```

An important subtlety in this answer is the line of code `t(x)[-c(1,2),]` in the anonymous function within `lapply()`. Since the result of `t(x)` is an object, we can immediately use the `[` form of the extract operator to remove the first two rows.